# Did Maggie Smith compare religion to a penis?

Tags: quotes

This [Twitter post](https://twitter.com/phemale61/status/398154962082865152) ([amongst many other](https://www.google.com.sg/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=UlL-VY34KomW8QfF47agBQ&gws_rd=ssl#safe=off&q=maggie%20smith%20religion%20penis) online references) attributes the quote to Maggie Smith:

> My dear, religion is like a penis. It's a perfectly fine thing for one
>   to have and take pride in, but when one takes it out and waves it in
>   my face we have a problem.

Did Maggie Smith make such a comment?

[image]

Comment: Picture of Smith being behind the photo doesn't necessarily mean the quote is attributed to her in that post. Find a notable claim, this is not enough.

Comment: @GeorgeChalhoub A quick google search shows many cases of people attributing it to Maggie Smith. Added the link.

Comment: A glance over the google results suggests that *possibly* it's rather her character in *A Room with a View* saying that. Anybody have the script or DVD to check?

Comment: It's most definitely not from Downton Abbey - the quote appears in a Reddit thread (https://www.reddit.com/comments/d8p14/religion_is_like_a_penis/) from Sept 2, 2010, when the first episode of Downton Abbey was released at the end of that month. A comment in the thread also claims that the quote appeared in a picture in March of that year, but that link is dead (or possibly blocked for my computer).

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I think it would appear on the movie's IMDB quote page if that were the case.

Comment: Found an earlier source: January 2009, look for a comment by "Personal Failure". http://www.atheistrev.com/2008/06/witnessing-to-atheists.html This might just be the origin. The comment is given its own article by the blog author at the end of the year, which would fit with the image link from the Reddit thread (early 2010).

Comment: @Hagen: At least, Forster's novel is on Project Gutenberg. It doesn't contain the word "penis", and the three occurrences of the word "religion" are not in any context resembling this quote. If it is a line from the film, it must be very freely adapted from the novel.

Comment: @NateEldredge: It’s not in the film of *Room with a View*, and would be quite jarringly off tone if it were.  (The film does have a famous nude bathing scene featuring very good views of Rupert Graves, Julian Sands, and Simon Callow, but it’s very tastefully done.)

Comment: It is not a line from "A Room With a View" There's nothing even remotely like it in the film.

Comment: A Russian blogger attempted to trace it [here](https://vadim-proskurin.livejournal.com/590278.html) and [here](https://vadim-proskurin.livejournal.com/590467.html). He found precursors going back to 2003.

Comment: This just looks line an [image macro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_macro). It's not meant to be a quote from the person pictured, just something a person who looks like that might say.